# Post man retuning null file, even file is uploaded

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

**strong text**Im try to uploade a file using Asp core webApi and using IFormFile.When im try test it with postman it always show null file, even file is uploaded correctly(i think it was correct).

I try many differnt files on postman.
remove the ApiController attribute, which some case suggested

Here are my code for uploade file:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile([FromForm]IFormFile 
                                                 fileData)
    {

        try
        {
            if (fileData == null) return BadRequest("null file");
            if (fileData.Length == 0)
            {
                return BadRequest("empty file");
            }

            var folderName = Path.Combine("resources", "iles");
            var pathToSave =  Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), folderName);



            var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(fileData.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

            var fullpath = Path.Combine(pathToSave, fileName);
            using (var stream = new FileStream(fullpath, 
                   FileMode.Create))
            {
                await fileData.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }

            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, "internal server error");
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few people in my team have had this same problem. When POSTing a file, you need to make sure that the name of the `key` field matches up with the name of the parameter in your controller's action. In your case, that means the `key` field should be `fileData`:

[image: key field in Postman]